# SPFx app with React Router Dom not working in Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams, sharepoint-online, web-parts, spfx, sharepointframework

I have created an SPFx React solution for custom development in SharePoint Online.

I have taken reference from the [Create a Single Page App in SPFx using React Router Dom](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/single-page-app-in-spfx-using-re/) link.

Now, I need to add the same SPFx app to the Teams tab. So, I have taken reference from the [How To Use SharePoint Framework (SPFx) In Teams To Build An App](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-use-sharepoint-framework-spfx-in-teams-to-build-an-app) link.

When I published the app in the SharePoint App Catalog and add that app to the SharePoint site page the routes worked as expected. But I published the same app to the Teams tab routes not worked as expected. It showing blank under the Teams tab.

Can anyone help me with the same?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please refer to the document below and follow the steps mentioned in the document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/sharepoint/dev/spfx/deployment-spfx-teams-solutions#developer-provided-microsoft-teams-app-manifest--package

Comment: Hello @thedeepponkiya - Could you please check the console log and share the error details if any?